# Why named arguments for django model classes

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I want to know that why do we specify names for parameters for model classes like `CharField` in django.like this for example.

```
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
```

why not

```
first_name = models.CharField(40, True)
```

In java we call `new charField(40,true)` like this.If they are default arguments we specify these in the definition of constructor (in java).

Why are we writing here.please,explain.

Comment: In particular, Python does not have method overloading like Java does, so you can't have multiple versions of the same method with different arguments. Since `max_length` and `blank` are not the first two positional arguments, you'd have to use `models.CharField(None, None, False, 40, False, True)`, having to explicitly match each default value of the preceding positional arguments. You can see why keyword arguments are preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see in java is called `positional arguments` where the arguments are always in certain order. Python, however, supports two type of arguments: [positional arguments and keyword arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-argument).

The beauty of keyword arguments being that while using the function you don't have to worry about defining values for all the arguments used within the method (or class constructor).

You can just use an `identifier` e.g. in your case `max_length` and `blank` and leave rest of the arguments as they are.

If you look at the [`__init__`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L141) method of the [`Field`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L97) class (*superclass of CharField*), you will find a number of keyword arguments defined there:

```
def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, name=None, primary_key=False,
        max_length=None, unique=False, blank=False, null=False,
        db_index=False, rel=None, default=NOT_PROVIDED, editable=True,
        serialize=True, unique_for_date=None, unique_for_month=None,
        unique_for_year=None, choices=None, help_text='', db_column=None,
        db_tablespace=None, auto_created=False, validators=[],
        error_messages=None):
```

Out of these, you just defined `max_length` and `blank` because that's what you required.